# how to display a single value from json in electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have an Electron app where I am executing a local script and returning json output.  I can display all json but no way I can display a single value.

script in HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">
const { exec } = require("child_process");

const test = exec("cd /home/user/Desktop/Wallet && ./wallet --format json balance", (error, stdout, stderr) => {

    if (error) {
        console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
        return;
    }
    if (stderr) {
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        return;
    }
   const test = (`data: ${stdout}`);

   console.log(test);

});
</script>
```

In the console log, I am getting this printed

```
data: [
  {
    "address": "134JGdUZauF3c8zxF9yzipGdojv6XGSmW5exCDiQM1wWJfGXXXY",
    "balance": 0.1,
    "dc_balance": 0,
    "sec_balance": 0.0
  }
]
```

but I can't get a print for `balance` or `address` only, whatever I do is always `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `stdout` arg contains output( json string ) generated by a child process. It just a string. You need to parse that json output to get the data:

```js
try
{
  const data = JSON.parse( stdout )
  console.log( `Adress:${data[ 0 ].address}` )
}
catch( err )
{
  throw Error( "Failed to parse json output.Reason:\n" + err )
}
```

Comment: that is what i got `Adress:undefined`

Comment: got this need to be `console.log( Adress:${data[0]["address"]}`